# Cannot read CMVideoDimensions structure with Objective C code

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have an `AVCaptureDevice` object at hand and would like to print the maximum supported photo dimensions as provided by `activeFormat.supportedMaxPhotoDimensions` (*), using Objective C. I tried the following:

```
for (NSValue *obj in device.activeFormat.supportedMaxPhotoDimensions) {
  CMVideoDimensions *vd = (__bridge CMVideoDimensions *)obj;
  NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"res=%d:%d", vd->width, vd->height];
  //print that string
}
```

If I run this code, I get:

```
res=314830880:24994
```

This is way too high, and there is obviously something I am doing wrong, but I don't know what it could be? According to the information I see on the web, I should get something closer to `4000:3000`.

I can successfully read `device.activeFormat.videoFieldOfView` and other fields, so I believe my code is sound overall.

(*) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/format/3967581-supportedmaxphotodimensions